# Find height of trapezoid / non-standard bottle thread

Tags: math

I'm doing some calculations of non-standard bottle threads. Calculation for height of trapezoid

I have the following trapezoid how can I find the height?

```
Leg1 = 1.17
Leg2 = 1.17
Base1 = 0.5
Base2 = 1.0
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `Leg1==Leg2`, you need to find the missing side of the rectangular triangle with the hypotenuse being `Leg1` and the other side being `(Base2-Base1)/2`.

```
Heigth = sqrt(Leg1^2-((Base2-Base1)/2)^2)`
```

Now, when both legs are different, introduce some variables:

```
l1 = Leg1
l2 = Leg2
b = Base2 - Base1
c1: the base of the triangle for Leg1
c2: the base of the triangle for Leg2
h: the height of both triangles
```

Then you get a set of equations:

```
c1 + c2 = b
h^2 + c1^2 = l1^2
h^2 + c2^2 = l2^2
```

Which can be solved for `h`:

```
h = sqrt( (l1 + l2 - b)*(l1 + l2 + b)*(b - l1 + l2)*(b + l1 - l2) )/(2*b)
```

which also can be written as:

```
h = sqrt(((l1 + l2)^2 - b^2) * (b^2 - (l1 - l2)^2)) / (2 * b)
```

or also

```
h = sqrt((((l1 + l2))^2 - b^2) * (1 - ((l1 - l2)/b)^2)) / 2
```